# How to inject external modules to an AngularJS single page application without injector/modulerr?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new on AngularJS and I have problems each time I follow a tutorial and add an external module. And I have some questions about how not to get injection errors.

**Q1.** How I can solve the injector/module problem? I have used bower to install 'ngSanitize', included in the HTML like:

```
<body ...>

 <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ngSanitize/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

**Q2.** If the order of adding the modules affects the results, is there a plugin for NetBeans, or an online application to check modules dependencies so they can be added in order?

**Q3.** Finally, what are the correct steps to inject external modules to an AngularJS single page application without injector/modulerr?

***Original:***

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'ngAnimate', 
    'angularMoment', 
    'angular-preload-image',
    'truncate',
    'app.core'
  ]);
```

**Objective situation** that throws injection error for 'ngSanitize':

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute', 
    'ngSanitize', 
    'ngAnimate', 
    'angularMoment', 
    'angular-preload-image',
    'truncate',     
    'app.core' 
  ]);
```

[The displayed error that crashes the application loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhPQB.png)

I got the same error using angularjs.org/1.4.8.

Comment: You should use `angular-sanitize.js` instead of `ngSanitize/index.js`.

Comment: I'll try, then When to use  the min version or the other one?


 <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I think is from using that specific ngSanitize.

You should install it using: `bower install angular-sanitize` and not `bower install ngSanitize`.

Despite being related to the same thing, `ngSanitize` is, according to it's repo description:

> angular-sanitize module without including angular.js for Backbone and
>   other frameworks

As you can see they belong to different repos:

**angular-sanitize:** https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize

**ngSanitize:** https://github.com/gdi2290/ngSanitize

Script loading in HTML is important. I always start by inserting `jQuery`, then `angular`, then angular specific modules like (`angular-animate`, `angular-sanitize`, etc) and then my custom angular modules scripts.

Regarding Q3, I don't think you messed up with module injection. It just showed that error because of using `ngSanitize` instead of `angular-sanitize`.